# Setting template data context with Router.go

Tags: meteor, iron-router

With iron router I can set the data context of a template like so:

`Router.route('hello', {data: {greeting: 'hello'}})`

So if my `hello.html` looks like this:

```
<template name="hello">
  <h1>{{greeting}}</h1>
</template>
```

I get, as expected, a page saying **hello**.

Question:
Can I do this with `Router.go()`?
According to what I've read, this should work:

```
Router.go('hello', {greeting: 'Whazaaaaaaa'})
```

But all I get is a boring **hello**. Is it possible to set the data in this way? If the second argument in Router.go isn't for data, then what is it for?

Answer (score 0):

yeah that should work. the second argument is passed to the route function as a parameter, so you need to set that one up accordingly. try this:

```
Router.route('/hello/:greeting', {
  template: 'hello',
  data: function() {
    return {greeting: this.params.greeting};
  }
});
```

now you can call:

```
Router.go('hello', {greeting: 'Whazaaaaaaa'})
```

Comment: Do I need to use the :_greeting in the route?

Comment: this.params undefined

Comment: try something like: Router.route('/hello/:_greeting', {data: {greeting: this.params._greeting?this.params.greeting:'hello'}});

Comment: sorry my bad, updated the answer. the code now works

Comment: So the second parameter isn't data, it's just to set parameters that are used in the url route?

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to change my route name (by adding :greeting to it). I want to explicitly set the data context, either using only Router.go() or both that and Router.route(). I haven't found very in-depth documentation on iron router functions, but so far it sounds like I can't do what I want.